# MAX value of a two column primary key in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'commesse' that is like this:

```
 year    id    field1     field2
 2014    1      asd         asd
 2014    2      asd         asd
 2015    1      asd         asd
 2015    2      asd         asd
```

Where first year and id are PK.
I need a query that extract the last row, that is to say this line:

```
 2015    2      asd         asd
```

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT MAX( year ) , MAX( id )
FROM commesse
GROUP BY year
HAVING year = MAX( year )
ORDER BY year DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

but I have the feeling that is a workaround, in fact I had to limit the result and order the value since that query extract both "2014 2 asd asd" and "2015 2 asd asd".
Is there a clean way to query the table in order to obtain only that line?
Hope I well explained my problem.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: what @Strawberry means is that in mysql there is no inherent ordering.. meaning that the way data is inserted is not a reliable order as MySQL can select the rows in any way it wants to. my assumption in my answer is that you meant the last row you showed in the question.. aka the largest year and id. but feel free to clarify if thats incorrect.

Comment: @DavideNava if my answer solved your issue can you please go ahead and accept it? it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

if all you want is the one row with the largest id and year you can just order it and limit like so

```
SELECT * FROM commesse
ORDER BY year DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ac596/1)